# Specific lilyglyph gives me Undefined control sequence error in Latex

Tags: pdftex, lilypond

I've been using musical lilyglyphs in a large latex document (e.g. `\crotchet`, `\quaver`, etc.)
without any problem, but when I try to use `\semibreve` or `\wholeNote` I get 2 errors in the same line:

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> {\fontspec
```

and

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ilyOpticalSuffix .otf}\lilyGetGlyph
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: you should show an example but `\fontspec` is defined by the `fontspec` package and needs luatex or xetex not, as you have tagged, pdftex

Comment: You're completely right, but it's difficult to reproduce this in a simple example as it is a multi-chapter doc with 2 definition files. I'm using pdflatex and I was using lilyglyphs without any issue until know. I'll have to investigate more but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Just had the same issue.  I'm using `latexmk -pdf`.  The answer for me was to `\usepackage{fontspec}` and use `latexmk -pdflua` to invoke lualatex.